# How to move(with animation) a cell's colored container from one position to another inside generated List from grid view count in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-packages

Here, I have a list. a = [92,93,94,95,81,66,51,36..];

I just want to move my colored cell's container according to the list index with animation.

To understand my question better, in the given image, I want to animate that cell container which is located at index 92, according to a list(a).

[image: Image Example]

Comment: @pskink  I want to animate it with a random position according to the list value. Like from list position 0 to 4. Here I am creating a ludo game in Flutter. So here, I want to move the position accounting to the dice value, which is gonna a random number from (1-6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we know the box size, we can use `getPosition()` method to position the circle.

```dart
 Offset getPosition(int index) {
    assert(boxWidth != null, "init boxWidth inside layoutBuilder");
    final dx = index <= crossAxisCount
        ? index * boxWidth!
        : (index % crossAxisCount) * boxWidth!;
    final dy = index <= crossAxisCount
        ? 0.0
        : (index / crossAxisCount).floor() * boxWidth!;
    return Offset(dx, dy);
  }
```

Use like

```dart
AnimatedPositioned(
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
  left: getPosition(currentPosition).dx,
  top: getPosition(currentPosition).dy,
  child: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    width: constraints.maxWidth / crossAxisCount,
    height: constraints.maxWidth / crossAxisCount,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: Colors.cyanAccent,
    ),
  ),
),
```

**Full Snippet On [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e7a060aea8b9aa95e42e2dc83a34e886)**